# To get the value of ng-model from jsp page to angular js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angular-controller

I have a jsp in which am assigning a value that is obtained from a java class to `ng-model` and am initializing the model with that value.

I want to get the value in the controller and save this value in a variable.

However,am unable to get the value in my controller though the value is getting set in the `ng-model`.(I have checked that).

Kindly help me. I am new to angular js and i think am making some small mistake here but am unable to figure it out.

**Code in the controller :**

```
    .controller('Ctrl', function($scope,$routeParams,$location) {

 $scope.name = "Ctrl";
 $scope.params = $routeParams;

$scope.user={};
 $scope.name=$scope.user.name;
 console.log('This is the value'+$scope.user.name);

})
```

**jsp code :**

```
   <input ng-show=true name="username"  type="text" ng-model= "user.name"    value=${UserName} ng-init="user.name='${UserName}'"/>
```

Comment: `$scope.user={}; $scope.name=$scope.user.name;` - this means you are overwriting `$scope.name` to `undefined`.

Comment: I tried without $scope.user={}; at first but it was throwing error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" for $scope.user.name.

Comment: You need to show us more of your code. Right now `$scope.name=$scope.user.name;` seems to be the only thing you are doing wrong.

Comment: I just want that value to be fetched in the controller as of now.